# how to apply jquery to different divs

Tags: jquery

I am looking to have a modified scroll bar on different divs, now it only aplies for . content

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
```

how do I write a correct code that it will apply the same jquery function to the div .post?
I have tried a few things but can´t get it staight..

Answer (score 1):

Use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) - separate the different selectors using `,`

```
$(".content, .post").mCustomScrollbar({
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create function where you can put your custom logic as follows:

```
var custom_logic = function(e)
{
   // Your logic here
};
```

or

```
function custom_logic(e)
{
   // Your logic here
}
```

and add as call back function to .mCustomeScrollbar()

```
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar(custom_logic);
$(".post").mCustomScrollbar(custom_logic);
```

It is reasonable if you are executing same logic not only for .mCustomeScrollbar but other functions as well. Or you adopt the method provided by @ArunPJohny.